# Javascript to fix header and change logo size on joomla theme when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

can someone help me to make my header fix on top and change logo size(or change to a different logo) when scrolling? I'use joomla 2.5 and the theme is gavickpro music free.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
var sc = $(window).scrollTop()
if (sc > 50) {
    $("#gkPageTopk").addClass("big")
} else {
    $("#gkPageTop").removeClass("big")
}
```

});

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't see how your question involves Java.

Comment: LOL,can help me with the right code?

Answer (score 0):

You may have just had a typo in your code.  Your first selector was different than the second.  I corrected and got rid of the variable declaration.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $("#gkPageTop").addClass("big")
    } else {
        $("#gkPageTop").removeClass("big")
    }
}
```

Also, the assumption here is that some element with the id="gkPageTop" class="big" will have altered CSS to make your element render the way you want...when the user has scrolled down more than 50 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might work. Joomla version doesn't matter. Make sure jQuery is working.

If still fail, try out like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll () {
 alert("scroll event detected! " + window.pageXOffset + " " + window.pageYOffset);
 // note: you can use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to access the width and height of the viewing area
}
</script>
```

Modify scroll function. Use `pageYOffset`